# Does the Linux file cache buffer belongs to a certain segment of page table?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

If yes, then which segment?
If no, then how OS manage the buffer?

Comment: What is "segment of page table" means? I have failed to understand the question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  such as, text segment,  data segment, stack, heap

Comment: `.text`, `.data` an so are **ELF segments**, they are unrelated to page table.

Comment: @Tsyvarev when an program is loaded to memory. The OS will allocate address chunk in page table for each segment like text, data.. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, ELF segments are **mapped** when a program is loaded into memory. But naming this mapping as a "segment of page table" is bad. There are two "caches" of the file's content: one is supported by the program (in the `libc` library), and another one is in the kernel. Which cache you ask about? If the program's one, then this is not a question about the kernel, so "linux-kernel" tag isn't applicable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What name is suitable?  And I care about kernel cache. I now recognize the cache I cared about is not in some segment....it is in the kenel address space

Comment: Hm, you may call them as "program segments". As for the question, I cannot answer it for sure. But cache buffer does definitely not belong to `text` or `data` segments as they are not extendable, nor it belongs to `stack` because file cache is not process-binded. As for the `heap`, Linux kernel has specific meaning of it, which differs from one of the user-space programs.

Comment: I would suggest you to [edit] your question and make it understandable *without reading the comments*.